# Automatically Passing Props on Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have created an `Input` component that I have styled with Styled Components.  I am now using that Input component with `Formik`.  I would like to be able to automatically set the `onChange`, `onBlur` and `value` props rather than have to set them each and every time (like what happens if I would use the Formik `Field` component).

That is, right now this is how my component looks when used:

```
<Input
  name="firstName"
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={values.firstName}
/>
```

What I would like the component to look like when being used is this:

```
<Input name="firstName" />
```

Then, behind the scenes, `onBlur` would be set to `handleBlur`, `onChange` would be set to `handleChange` and `value` would be set to `values.[name]`.  That is, to the value of the `name` prop.  So, in this example, it would be set to `values.firstName`.  If the `name` prop was set to `lastName`, then the `value` prop would automatically be set to `values.lastName`.

Any idea how I can do this?

**NOTE:** I know that the `Field` prop from Formik does this, but I want to use my custom `Input` component instead.

**UPDATE**

Here is some other code that may be relevant to answering this question.

*Input Component*

```
export const Input = props => {
  const {
    forId,
    name,
    placeholder,
  } = props

  const titleCase = startCase(name)

  return (
    <InputBase {...props}>
      <InputSection>
        <InputContent
          id={forId ? forId : name}
          placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : titleCase}
          type="text"
          {...props}
        />
      </InputSection>
    </InputBase>
  )
}
```

*InputContent Component*

```
export const InputContent = styled.input`
  // STYLES
`
```

*Formik with Form*

```
<Formik
  render={props => {
    const {
      handleBlur,
      handleChange,
      values,
    } = props

    return (
      <Form>
        <Input
          name="firstName"
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.firstName}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    )
  }}
  initialValues={{firstName: ''}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
/>
```

Comment: I fear there is no way around this, you'll need to pass down the appropriate props even if you make your own custom component, another option is to make the whole form an uncontrolled component.

Comment: @Rohit As far as I understand, the `Field` component from Formik does.  I think they use context - but I don't know how.

Comment: Oh, context huh? Haven't really gotten up to speed on the latest react features. As I mentioned, uncontrolled components are also an option.

Comment: I'd like to keep this a controlled component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is good idea. But what you can do is create HOC and wrap it

```
// lasyWrapper.js
export function lazyWrapper(Input) {
  return LazyWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Input
          {...this.props}
          name={this.props.name}
          onBlur={this.props.handleBlur}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
          value={this.props.values[this.props.name]}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}


// Input.js
export default lazyWrapper(Input)

// use somewhere
<Input
  name="firstName"
  {...this}
/>
```

But this is really **BAD** idea.

Comment: you'll need to pass down the props as well.